Roundcube SMTP remote server 465 SSL port no connect
EDITED!
Without SSL, only the server address and port 25 works properly, but i want to use SSL.
Original:
I use an old server for mail service, and i use a new server for webpages.
I installed Roundcube to webserver, and work fine... If i only read mails. So imap works, but SMTP not. What is the problem? This config works properly from old server.
$config['smtp_log'] = true;
$config['smtp_debug'] = true;
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://mail.domain.tld:465';
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';

I want to separate mail server and webpages.
In my old server's mail.log can not see smtp connecting attempts from new server, only imap.
This is in my errors.log (in roundcube logs dir):
[2024-Aug-17 08:10:34 +0000]: <j92l4ng8> PHP Error: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1723882234954&_framed=1&_lang=hu&_action=send)
[2024-Aug-17 08:10:34 +0000]: <j92l4ng8> PHP Error: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1723882234954&_framed=1&_lang=hu&_action=send)
[2024-Aug-17 08:10:34 +0000]: <j92l4ng8> SMTP Error: Connection failed:  (Code: -1) in /var/www/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php on line 1794 (POST /?_task=mail&_unlock=loading1723882234954&_framed=1&_lang=hu&_action=send)

Thank you.

The error message ssl://mail.domain.tld:465 (Connection refused) means that
the target host mail.domain.tld isn't configured to listen for connection on port 465 or this host has a firewall that prohibits connections to this port from your host.

Thanks. This is interesting because other mail clients works well.

I'am not a linux expert at all, but I see a possible error. The certificate is most likely not accepted if you use a self-signed certificate, thus the connection fail.
I would add that to the configuration if possible;
$config['smtp_conn_options'] = array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
),
);

Unfortunately this not works. Other warn collected:
[17-Aug-2024 08:01:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://mail.domain.tld:465 (Connection refused) in /var/www/webmail/vendor/pear/net_socket/Net/Socket.php on line 158
